# WSO2 API Manager BAM SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wso2

We are trying to setup WSO2 API Manager and the WSO2 BAM with a SQL Server database. When trying to view the BAM Dashboard in the API Store we are getting the following error:

> ERROR usage:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage - Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

After tracing the DB we found the following query which is causing the error:

```
SELECT CONSUMER_KEY,NAME 
FROM AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING  
NATURAL JOIN AM_APPLICATION  
NATURAL JOIN AM_SUBSCRIBER WHERE USER_ID = 'admin'
```

Since `NATURAL JOIN` is not supported in SQL Server, is there any way to get the API Manager and BAM to work with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If the query is being passed to MS SQL Server, you will need to re-write this query using T-SQL which would be something like this.....

```
SELECT  [TableName].CONSUMER_KEY
        ,[TableName].NAME 
FROM       AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING  
INNER JOIN AM_APPLICATION  
           ON AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING.CommonColumn   = AM_APPLICATION.CommonColumn
INNER JOIN AM_SUBSCRIBER   
           ON [One of the Previous Tables].CommonColumn = AM_SUBSCRIBER.CommonColumn
WHERE [TableName].[USER_ID] = 'admin'
```